# Can virtual memory exists without Paging concept?

Tags: operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

We usually learn Virtual memory and Paging at the same time in Operating System and they seem dependent. However, I wonder if they exist independently of each other?

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on how you define "Virtual Memory". If you define it just as "the addresses that the application sees", then yes Virtual Memory can exist without paging.

Prior to paging, systems used segmentation to isolate user processes. To put it in simple words every process has it's own segment. All the addresses it "sees" are just offsets inside the segment. The hardware implicitly adds the segment base to the address requested by the application to get the Physical addresses. Just like the page table, the segment bases can be modified only by the kernel and it can effectively isolate memory for processes at the same time allowing scope for sharing some parts of memory between processes too.

Segments also have limits which are checked before every access to ensure that the user doesn't use a very big offset and spill into other process.

Segmentation support has been removed from Intel X86_64 architectures where the segment registers do exist but are always set to 0. Only the two segment registers `%fs` and `%gs` continue to exist. But the limit checks on them is not performed by the hardware. These segments are now used by the OS for thread local storage.

Comment: Thank you. This answer helps.